# Can I automate discord actions with python?

Tags: python, api, discord

I want to set up a python script that runs automatically in some situations which opens different programs and among other things joins my main discord voice channel. I figured out most of it, but with discord I am struggling so far. Every tutorial I found is for dicord bots - that's not what I am looking for. I want my currently logged in user to join a specific channel if that channel is available.

I already tried to just copy the link for that channel and use the `webbrowser` module:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://discord.com/channels/some_channel_id/some_other_id')
```

But that uses the browser, and I have not found a way for it to open in discord yet.

The tutorials was speaking of earlier all need an api token. I would prefer if I don't need one, to keep the dependencies as small as possible.

I already worked with somewhat similar apis (telegram for example), and I can imagine that there's no way without a token.

But just to be sure, is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed open a link in the discord app with the `webbrowser` module in python.

Here's an example code:

```
import webbrowser

# Discord link to open
discord_link = "https://discord.com/channels/some_channel_id/some_other_id"

# Use the "discord://" protocol handler to open the link in the Discord app
discord_protocol_link = discord_link.replace("https://", "discord://")
webbrowser.open_new(discord_protocol_link)
```

You (of course) need the discord app on your PC in order for this to work. If you have any questions or problems, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Wow, that was easy - thank you! 
Sadly that doesn't auto-join the channel and there is still a user action needed, but that's not part of the question, I will take a deeper look - thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe I can find a solution for that too.

Comment: According to my research, the link should already make the user join without further interaction - (chatGPT is supporting that information) but regardless of the channel or server I try, I always need to click 'Join Voicechannel' manually - I appreciate it if you find something, but no worries if you don't :)